# xpath : get 2nd href link to last

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I want to know how to get href link from position 2nd to last,

This is my xpath :

```
date = sel.xpath("//div[@class='date']//ul/li/a/@href").extract()
```

And it get result like :

```
[u'http://www.job.com/?date=12/15/2014', u'hhttp://www.job.com/?date=12/16/2014', u'http://www.job.com/?date=12/17/2014', u'http://www.job.com/?date=12/18/2014']
```

And I don't want the first one `http://www.job.com/?date=12/15/2014`

I want to choose `li[2]` to the last `li`
How can I do this?
Please guide me
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
date = sel.xpath("//div[@class='date']//ul/li[position() >= 2]/a/@href").extract()
```